# Scrape number of tweets for certain Twitter accounts

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, topsy

I need to scrape the exact number of tweets that are generated under certain Twitter accounts on a daily basis. As well as the number of followers.

As far as I know Twitter's streaming API is not complete.

Does anyone know a suitable source - not necessarily from Twitter. I am already scraping from Topsy but I could not figure out yet how to limit the displayed tweets to only a single account. I do not even need the content but only the number of generated tweets and the number of followers.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Does somebody maybe have another idea. The answer down there does not really work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several python modules](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#python) that can be used.

Here is how you could go about getting a list of followers with Twython

(from: [How to get twitter followers using Twython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963792/how-to-get-twitter-followers-using-twython))

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython()
followers = twitter.get_followers_ids(screen_name = "ryanmcgrath")

for follower_id in followers:
    print "User with ID %d is following ryanmcgrath" % follower_id
```